# How do I get all the friends who have liked an object for a list of objects?

Tags: python, sql, django, database-design

I have two models: Like and Object.  How can I retrieve the corresponding set of people who liked the object using the following models:

```
class Object(models.Model):
    ...

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    object = models.ForeignKey(Object)

friends = [...some list of ids...]
```

I thought about this two ways: either using Object or using Like, but neither works.  For example:

```
Object.objects.prefetch_related('like_set').filter(like__user__in=friends)
```

This gets the corresponding set of likes for each object, but each like_set will contain *all* likes instead of those of my friends.

The other way is to go through Like:

```
Like.objects.select_related('object').filter(user__in=friends) \
                                     .order_by('-user_id').distinct('object')
```

But I believe this way will only get me one like per object.  So is there any way to get all the likes of my friends for each object?

EDIT: To clarify, I need the list of User objects corresponding to each Object object because I want to be able to print out their names.  I also want to minimize the number of queries and am open to using raw SQL.

Comment: This is a database design question. Can a user likes multiple objects here? I'd imagine Like is a supporting entity connecting User and Object relations. Besides, is this Object one relation, or can be different relations?
For example:  User likes Car, or User likes Animal.

Comment: Yes, a user can like multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want, but you really need a [`ManyToMany`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships) on your Friends model to Objects and call it `likes`.

```
from collections import Counter

likes_of_friends = Like.objects.filter(friends__in=friend_list)
objects_of_likes = likes_of_friends.values_list('object__pk',flat=True)
number_of_likes = dict(Counter(list(objects_of_likes)))

for key,val in number_of_likes.iteritems():
   print 'My friends like %s object %d times' % (Object.objects.get(pk=key),val)
```

Comment: `objects_of_likes` is typo of `all_likes`?

Comment: So if I added a ManyToMany field on my User model, how would that work? @burhan

Comment: If your m2m field is called `likes`, then you would do `Friends.objects.get(pk=1).likes.all()`

Answer (score 0):

*update*

```
objects = {}
for obj in Like.objects.filter(user__in=friends):
    objects.setdefault(obj.object, set()).add(obj.user)

# objects is a dict w/ object as key and the set of friends who like the object as the value
```

To get friends liking certain `object`

```
User.objects.filter(like__object=object, pk__in=friends) # .distinct() depends on your schema
```

To get all the like relationship between your friends and objects

```
Like.objects.filter(user__in=friends).order_by('user') # .distinct() depends on your schema
```

To get all friends for each objects that liked by friends

```
for obj in Object.objects.filter(like__user__in=friends).distinct():
    User.objects.filter(like__object=object).distinct()
```

Comment: This makes sense but I want to avoid making that many queries.  Can it be done in one query, maybe with custom SQL?